# Spring Security:DataBase authentication provider

Tags: java, database, authentication, spring-security, provider

Can't get `Spring Security` to work with DB authentication provider.
In-memory authentication provider works OK.

**Step to reproduce:**
when I logged with credentials `sb`,`sb`,`login()` method of `AuthenticationService` returned `false`.
There are no related log in `Tomcat`.

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/chirokDB?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**service layer:**

```
@Service("authenticationService")
   public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {
    @Resource(name = "authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        try {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    username, password));
            if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            }
            return false;
   }
```

**managed bean level:**

```
public String doLogin() {
    boolean isLoggedIn = authenticationService.login(name, password);
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        return "index";
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("login failure", new FacesMessage());
    return "failureLogin";
}
```

**applicationContext-security.xml:**

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>  
    <http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/index.xhtml"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/contacts.xhtml" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/delivery.xhtml" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <logout invalidate-session="true"/>
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
        </session-management>   
    </http>          

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**persistence level:**
`MySql DB` has following standard tables(required by Spring):
1. users
2. authorities

`users` table has record with username='sb' and password='sb'
`authorities` table has record with username='sb' and authority='ROLE_USER'

**note**
with user-in memory all works OK with following config:

```
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="sb" password="sb" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**assumption:**
`dataSource` injected into `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl`
As far Hibernate ORM used, perhaps some other than `JdbcDaoImpl` should be used?

Comment: In what sense does it not work?

Comment: jtoberon,I've update my post. See "Step to reproduce" section,please.

Comment: What's an AuthenticationService?

Comment: AuthenticationService is just simple interface with login() method.About exception,you're right,I'll investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're getting an `Exception` in your empty catch block (which always is a bad idea).

Comment: jtoberon,thank you for hint,I've got: `PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]`

Comment: continue:`org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'enabled' in 'field list'` Looks like I should provide one more field, called `enabled`,but why? I created table users according to Spring docs.

Comment: Oh,I'm wrong,there was such field,called `enabled`: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html

Comment: no prob -- it's often the easy stuff that wastes the most time!