# How to apply Spring Security on Struts 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, struts2

I have read various tutorials and forums but have not found a working example of combination of Spring security and struts2  to investigate the coding. Most of the current examples are using the predefined username and passwords in the XML file but not connected to database.

Examples:

- [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607719/how-use-spring-security-3-on-struts-2)
- [Sample 2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/528561/Spring/Spring-Spring-Security-Struts-Hibernate)
- [Sample 3](http://jtechspace.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/integrating-struts2-with-spring.html)

Please let me know if you know of any example or tutorial.

Comment: What's the specific issue? The mechanism used to store credentials shouldn't impact on the web framework, no? You just need a DB authentication provider (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416021/spring-securitydatabase-authentication-provider, or any number of other tutorials, blogs, etc.)

Comment: @DaveNewton the issue is that I am newbie and need to have a look at the code to understand it, but I cant find any.

Comment: Well... those links had some code, and searching for "spring security db authentication provider" seems to turn up quite a lot of information, e.g., http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ or http://arielsweb.com/?p=115. What other information do you need???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably start with these tutorials:

- [Spring Security Part 1 – Simple Login application with database](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/spring-security-part-1-simple-login.html)
- [Spring Security Part 2 – Password Encryption, Customize 404 and 403 error page](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/spring-security-part-2-password.html)

Comment: I have downloaded the code but it does not work. do you know of any other sample similar to this ?